# Asociar nombre de dominio en Amazon Web Service

Tags: wordpress, aws, dns, dominio, ec2

he creado una pagina estatica con WORDPRESS en AWS en EC2, creé la instancia y demás (la pagina esta funcionado). Pero, el problema surge porque no puedo asociar el nombre de dominio que compre (en NIC Argentina) con la pagina que creé. Segui los pasos de la documentacion de AWS y no pasa nada. vi un video en YOUTUBE segui los pasos y en una parte me dice para conectarme con la instancia a través de SSH y me aparece el siguente mensaje.

*Instance is not associated with a key pair*

*This instance is not associated with a key pair. You can still connect to the instance using EC2 Instance Connect if you provide a valid user name. To connect using a standalone or Java SSH client, you need both a valid user name and a password.*

Mi pregunta: Si alguien sabe como asociar el nombre de dominio con la direccion de mi pagina en ROUTER 35 o como genero el par de llaves de la instancia para conectarme a la misma por SSH. 
Saludos.

Comment: Por lo que se comenta en el error, no se esta asociando la instancia con el key pair, primero revisa como hacer esta acción. Saludos @Arevalo Matias

Answer (score 0):

El keir pair sirve para que te puedas conectar por medio de ssh a tu intancia ec2 para asociar tu dominio al la intancia ec2 debes primero crear el registro en route53 y en la instancia ec2 configurar un virtualhost con el nombre de dominio elegido.

Saludos

[image: Key pair para ec2]

Answer (score 0):

No es muy claro lo que buscas con la pregunta, sin embargo te respondo sobre como obtener acceso a la instancia y generar las llaves:

Cuando lanzaste la instancia no le definiste un key pair por lo que ya no te puedes conectar por SSH usando un cliente tradicional y deberás usar EC2 Connect, para usar este servicio necesitas que la instancia tenga una IP pública.

Puedes encontrar más información aquí:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Connect-using-EC2-Instance-Connect.html

Una vez te logres conectar a la instancias deberás generar un par de llaves desde el PC que te vas a conectar usando el comando:

```
 ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "username"
```

Tras generar el par de llaves con el asistente (Puedes simplemente pulsar Enter hasta terminar) te van a quedar dos archivos en la ruta ~/.ssh/ id_rsa y id_rsa.pub

Abre el archivo id_rsa.pub y copialo en el portapapeles (Es solamente una linea), ve al servidor que tienes abierto en EC2 instance conect, y ejecuta el siguiente comando

```
echo "pega el contenido de id_rsa.pub" >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Tras esto deberías poder conectarte usando un cliente SSH tradicional.